# Why TextDocumentContentProvider dont call provideTextDocumentContent on update when query params changes?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

as title says, when i wanna update TextDocumentContentProvider with different query params by calling `update` method `provideTextDocumentContent` is not called...

only way i managed to get it working was with same URI as in calling

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.previewHtml', URI, 2, 'Storybook');
```

relevant part of code:

```
// calculates uri based on editor state - depends on actual caret position
// all uris will start with 'storybook://preview'
function getPreviewUri(editor: vscode.TextEditor): vscode.Uri;

// transforms uri, so web server will understand
// ex: 'storybook://preview?name=fred' -> 'http://localhost:12345/preview/fred?full=1'
function transformUri(uri: vscode.Uri): vscode.Uri;

class StorybookContentProvider implements vscode.TextDocumentContentProvider 
{
  provideTextDocumentContent(uri: vscode.Uri): string {
    var httpUri = transformUri(uri);
    return `<iframe src="${httpUri}" />`; 
  }
  onDidChange = new vscode.EventEmitter<vscode.Uri>();
  update(uri: vscode.Uri) {
    this.onDidChange(uri);
  }
}
```

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext)
{
    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(
      (e: vscode.TextDocumentChangeEvent) => {
        if (e.document === vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document) {
          const previewUri = getPreviewUri(vscode.window.activeTextEditor);
          provider.update(previewUri);
        }
      }
    );

    vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection(
      (e: vscode.TextEditorSelectionChangeEvent) => {
        if (e.textEditor === vscode.window.activeTextEditor) {
          const previewUri = getPreviewUri(vscode.window.activeTextEditor);
          provider.update(previewUri);
        }
      }
    );

    const provider = new StorybookContentProvider();
    context.subscriptions.push(
      vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.showStorybook', () => {
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.previewHtml', vscode.Uri.parse('storybook://preview'), 2, 'Storybook')
      }),
      vscode.workspace.registerTextDocumentContentProvider('storybook', provider)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that it has been a long time since the question was asked, anyway I answer for future reference.

You have to create an event handler in your provider, and in the `update` method you have to emit the event with `fire`.

something like this:

```
    onDidChangeEmitter = new vscode.EventEmitter<vscode.Uri>();
    update(uri: vscode.Uri) {
        this.onDidChangeEmitter.fire(uri);
    }
```